# In LINQPad , what is the equivalent of C#'s .Dump() method in F#?

Tags: c#, f#, linqpad

In LINQPad , what is the equivalent of C#'s .Dump() method in F#?

For example, what is the quickest way to dump the below C# in F# syntax?

```
var nums = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
nums.Dump();
```

And

```
let nums = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works for me:

```
let nums = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
nums.Dump()
```

Comment: Am literally waiting for the 10 minute timer to tick down.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `Dump` as a function:

```
let nums = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
Dump nums
nums |> Dump
(* ... *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the already given `.Dump()` method, you should know it is also automatically invoked when you write a collection (and other types) to the console:

```
let nums = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
Console.WriteLine(nums);
```

will also give you the dump.

Answer (score 0):

This one can be used in the middle of a piped workflow too, because it return his input.

```
let DumpHelper (caption:string) a =
 a.Dump(caption)
 a
```

Comment: Note the regular `Dump` returns its input as well, you just can't call the caption variation.